# JIRA Connect 1.2.1 imported as CocoaPod results in linker error for armv7

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, hockeyapp, jira-mobile-connect

I'm trying to integrate both HockeyApp and JIRA Mobile Connect using CocoaPods, but linking fails for armv7. The CrashReporter framework seems to be in place but it complains about some PLCrashReporter symbol that can't be found for armv7 architecture.

The change I made to the project was to replace TestFlight SDK with HockeyApp SDK in the Podfile.

Any suggestions on how to fix the linking issue? Have still not tried putting back TestFlight SDK, and the project is based on the iOS 7 SDK.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: 
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_PLCrashReporter", referenced from: objc-class-ref in CrashReporter.o 
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_PLCrashReporter", referenced from: objc-class-ref in CrashReporter.o 
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is how my Podfile looks, I have a post install hook to set Base SDK to iOS 7.1. If I don't do this I have some issues with Metal framework being imported.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.0'

target 'HockeyWithJira' do
pod 'HockeySDK', '~> 3.6'
pod 'JIRAConnect', '~> 1.2.1'
end

# Post install hook
post_install do | installer |

    # Force iOS 7.1 SDK as "Base SDK" for Pods config
    installer.project.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'
        config.build_settings['SDKROOT'] = 'iphoneos7.1'
    end

    # Force iOS 7.1 SDK as "Base SDK"
    installer.project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'
            config.build_settings['SDKROOT'] = 'iphoneos7.1'
        end
    end
end
```

I now have a workaround for this, unfortunately I now have to manage the JIRA Connect library manually instead of using CocoaPod which is not ideal.

Comment: Please post the full error message you get in Xcode.

Comment: Added Xcode error message.

Comment: JIRA Mobile Connect comes with PLCrashReporter, HockeyApp too but it has a custom namespaced build so it can't collide with others. Since the message is referring to JIRA Mobile Connect I assume it is theirs. Try to build without JIRA Mobile Connect and see if that works. Then add it again. If it still fails, you need to provide more information.

Comment: @metalhead am facing a similar problem, Did u find a solution?

Comment: @akshaynhegde, at the moment I'm importing HockeyApp SDK using CocoaPods and Jira Mobile Connect from the redistributable package found on their web page. However I've gotten a bit bored by broken symlinks that appear after almost every merge in Mercurial so I'm planning to move on to the last resort in Mercurial "sub repos". I'll probably give this a shot within a month. Aiming to replace as many CocoaPods as possible with sub repos.